# Issue with Python Web-Application

Tags: python, mysql, web-applications

I am creating a web application of trails in MA. I want to be able to click on the name of a trail, and have its information displayed. I have a table called 'hiking' with 10 columns. Right now, when I click on the name of a trail, the only thing that displays on the page is ( ), just two parentheses and nothing else. I'm trying to a follow an example a professor gave me, but it seems I'm doing something wrong, but I can't really figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
def getHikeInfo(name):   
# connect to db
conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

# prepare SQL
sql = """
SELECT *
FROM hiking
WHERE name = %s
"""

# run the SQL
cursor.execute(sql, name)

# fetch the results
data = cursor.fetchall()

# clean up
cursor.close()
conn.close()

return data

################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "name" in form:
    name=form['name'].value
    print getHikeInfo(name)
```

Comment: as an aside check out the trails in Weston

Comment: @Drew hahaha, will do!!

Comment: You should write **if name in form:** without the double quotes

Comment: @rocksteady I don't think that will help, that produced an error within the application, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to put your `name` query parameter into a tuple:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (name, ))
```

And, if you only need a single row from the database, use `fetchone()`:

```
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: I tried what you said, and now instead of ( ), the web page just says 'None'.

Comment: @smoody I think it's just that there is no record in the table matching the name. Could you debug it and see what is the value of `name`?

Comment: 'name' is one of my column names in the table. I debugged it and the value of 'name' is the name of the trail (ex: key name=name, value=Wells State Park).

Comment: @smoody and, are you sure you have that name in the `hiking` table?

Comment: @smoody and a quick check, how about `cursor.execute(sql, (name.strip(), ))`?

Comment: Yes, 110%. I can't figure out what my issue is!

Comment: also, just tried that, and am still getting the ( ). But thank you so much for all your suggestions!!